# Including Angular-UI-Validate in my project

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui

The project uses Angular 1.3 (from a CDN, links removed below) and I'm trying to install Angular-UI-Validate. I have included both in script tags, and in the inspector, I can see that they're both getting retrieved correctly. Still, it seems as if I'm missing something:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.10/$injector/unpr?p0=ui.validateProvider%20%3C-%20ui.validate%20%3C-%20app.runtimeStackAdminController
    at Error (native)
    at https://***.cdn.net/1.5/libs/angular.js/1.3.10/angular.min.js:6:417
    at https://***.cdn.net/1.5/libs/angular.js/1.3.10/angular.min.js:38:307
    at Object.d [as get] (https://***.cdn.net/1.5/libs/angular.js/1.3.10/angular.min.js:36:308)
    at https://***.cdn.net/1.5/libs/angular.js/1.3.10/angular.min.js:38:381
    at d (https://***.cdn.net/1.5/libs/angular.js/1.3.10/angular.min.js:36:308)
    at e (https://***.cdn.net/1.5/libs/angular.js/1.3.10/angular.min.js:37:64)
    at Object.g.instantiate (https://l***.cdn.net/1.5/libs/angular.js/1.3.10/angular.min.js:37:213)
    at b.$get (https://***.cdn.net/1.5/libs/angular.js/1.3.10/angular.min.js:76:318)
    at $route.link (https://***.cdn.net/1.5/libs/angular.js/1.3.10/angular-route.js:981:26) <div id="ng-view-wrapper" class="container-fluid  ng-scope" ng-view="" autoscroll="true">
```

Am I missing a library that I have to include? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You need to load the ui.validate module.

See https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-validate#usage for all instructions.